# Lower bound of an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Is there a theorem or equation regarding the lower bound of an inner product?

If it helps, the specific application is the following:
I want to show $\sum\limits_\theta \frac{a_\theta}{c_\theta} (a_\theta - b_\theta) \ge 0 $

So $\frac{a_\theta}{c_\theta}$ is the first vector of the inner product and $(a_\theta - b_\theta)$ is the second.

Also:
$\sum\limits_\theta a_\theta = 1$

$\sum\limits_\theta b_\theta \le 1$

$\sum\limits_\theta c_\theta \le 1$

$a_\theta, c_\theta > 0$ for all $\theta$

$b_\theta \ge 0$ for all $\theta$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \frac12,  &  a_2 &= \frac12, \\
b_1 &= 0,        &  b_2 &= \frac34, \\
c_1 &= \frac12,  &  c_2 &= \frac1{100}. \\
\end{align}
Then
$$
\frac{a_1}{c_1} (a_1 - b_1) = \frac12,  \qquad
\frac{a_2}{c_2} (a_2 - b_2) = -25,
$$

$$
\sum\limits_\theta \frac{a_\theta}{c_\theta} (a_\theta - b_\theta) < 0.
$$

If $\theta$ was supposed to range over all positive integers,
just divide each of the previously-given values 
of $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_1$ by $2$
and set $a_\theta = b_\theta = c_\theta = 2^{1-\theta}$
for $\theta \geq 3$.